# Контекст в JS (this)

Tags: javascript, функции, область-видимости

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом коде в 1-м варианте так как у стрелочных функций нету `this` она берет `this` у "родителя" , а во 2-м варианте `this` вообще нету поэтому будет ошибка?

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Bob',
  city: ["Madrid", 'Rome', 'LA'],
  printLocation: function() {
    this.city.forEach(city => {
      console.log(`${this.name} live in ${city}`)
    })
  }
}

user.printLocation()

const user2 = {
  name: 'Bred',
  city: ["Madrid", 'Rome', 'LA'],
  printLocation: () => {
    this.city.forEach(city => {
      console.log(`${this.name} live in ${city}`)
    })
  }
}

user2.printLocation()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> а во 2м варианте this вообще нету

`this` есть, но в данном случае ссылается он на объект `window`. В стрелочных функциях, `this` подхватывает значение лексического контекста. Если простым словами, то значение `this` внутри стрелочной функции, будет таким же, как и снаружи. Однако, в ES6 появились именно `методы объекта` и для более короткого синтаксиса, можете использовать их:

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Bred',
  city: ["Madrid", 'Rome', 'LA'],
  printLocation() {
    this.city.forEach(city => {
      console.log(`${this.name} live in ${city}`);
    });
  }
};
user.printLocation();
```

Comment: То же самое что `printLocation: function()`

Comment: @RomanC, не совсем то же, но по сути да - это можно считать сокращенным синтаксисом, о чем я и написал выше.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Bob',
  city: ["Madrid", 'Rome', 'LA'],
  printLocation: function() {
    this.city.forEach(city => {
      console.log(`${this.name} live in ${city}`)
    })
  }
}

user.printLocation()

const user2 = {
  name: 'Bred',
  city: ["Madrid", 'Rome', 'LA'],
  printLocation: () => {
    user2.city.forEach(city => {
      console.log(`${user2.name} live in ${city}`)
    });
  }
}

user2.printLocation()
```